# How to get date("Y-m-d") from date("Y-m-d H:i:s")?

Tags: php, mysql

how can I get and store date('2017-02-02') in php variable from result : datetime("2017-02-02 17:02:03").

Comment: Is `datetime` a column in mysql?

Comment: yes there is datetime column.

Comment: Then you can select the date with the mysql function `DATE` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) - or use `strotime()` in PHP, use `DateTime` objects.. May ways to go about this.

Comment: All you need to know is right here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean getting `2017-02-02` from `2017-02-02 17:02:03`, well you have many options,

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03'));
```

OR

```
list($date) = explode(" ", '2017-02-02 17:02:03');
```

OR

```
    $arr = explode(" ", '2017-02-02 17:02:03');
    $date = array_shift($arr);
```

OR

```
 $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", '2017-02-02 17:02:03');
 $date = $dateObj->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: OR `$date = explode(" ", '2017-02-02 17:02:03')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the date to a timestamp with `strtotime()`

Example:

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03'));
?>
```

I hope this will help you!